# How do I define post titles as images using Custom Fields?

Tags: custom-field

I've tried to follow a guide that explain how to do so but failed and I don't know why it doesn't work.

The guide:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/unique-header-image-for-each-post

1. In my posts (WP GUI), I've added a custom field named 'PostTitle'.
   The value of these Posts are 153 & 156 as the post IDs numbers.
   Furthermore, I've uploaded two title pictures to my theme images directory:

   - http://letthemstare.com/wp-content/themes/manifest_v1.1/images/153.jpg
   - http://letthemstare.com/wp-content/themes/manifest_v1.1/images/156.jpg
2. Under header.php , I've added the following:

   ID, $myfield, true);
   ?>

   ```
   .entry-title {
       border:none;
       color:black;
     <?php
     if($postimage) { 
     ?>
       background-image: url('http://letthemstare.com/wp-content/themes/manifest_v1.1/images/<?php echo $postimage; ?>.jpg');
     <?php
     } elseif(!$postimage) { 
     ?>
       background-image: none;
     <?php
     }
     ?>
   }
   ```
3. Post titles images load to each post title individually but:

a. Images doesn't replace original text title
b. Images are shown only within posts and not on the main page
c. I'm not sure that the images will function as a link on the main page

I choose entry-title according to the following code in index.php:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <h3 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
```

When I mask this line, the post titles on the main page disappear. Furthermore, on style.css h3 represents the post titles:

```
h3 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
}
```

I'm afraid that I have a mistake in the title class but I don't know what it is and how to fix it. Kindly assist me in fixing the issues above. Your support would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That's a very old tutorial.

Since version 2.9, WP comes with post thumbnails built in:

http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/new-in-wordpress-2-9-post-thumbnail-images/